# Custom Fieldtype in a plugin at user profile save

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I have made a custom fieldtype.

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: "business"|t,
    required: true,
}) }}
```

And added it to the user fields.
Where do I need to save data entered in at a user profile.

I would like to hook into the `onSaveUser` event with my plugin to save my values into the address model of Craft Commerce, but how would I do that?

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is probably to use the [`onAfterElementSave`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType#onAfterElementSave-detail) hook available to custom fieldtypes. Here's what that could look like (the following method should go into your custom fieldtype class, e.g. `myawesomeplugin/fieldtypes/MyAwesomePluginFieldType.php`):

```
public function onAfterElementSave()
{
    $field = $this;
    $fieldId = $this->model->id;
    $fieldHandle = $this->model->handle;
    $element = $this->element; // This is the UserModel, in your case
    $fieldContent = $element->getContent()->getAttribute($fieldHandle); // This is the content for the field

    // Do something awesome with the data above
    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and i love the onAfterElementSave().
But i need to use the business field from my CustomField Type to be saved after the user is saved in a address model.

I am only getting the UserModel and not the AddressModel to populate it.